# how to find all non-conflict line segments from a lot of 2D segments?

Tags: python, geometry, intersection

I met a geometry/algorithm problem.

With help of a function, I can know if 2 segments intersect with each other, like

```
def intersect(P,Q):
 return True if P,Q intersect
```

based on this function, I want get something more.

I have around 100 segments, and wondering how can I get the quantity of classes of all non-conflict/intersect combinations (add: if you know a term in traffic management, I want to find something like PHASE)

for example, the following img link: I got 4 segments A, B, C and D.

[example: 4 segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBd8.png)

A intersect with B,C
C intersect with D

possible non-conflict/intersect combinations could be:

[A D], [B C], the class number is 2

or

[B D], [A], [C], the class number is 3

Is there anyway to get those combination list and the corresponding class number?

Any answer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting all non-intersecting pairs of segments you can do something like in the code below.

First of all you need to retrieve all segment coordinates from an external source (text file, json file, etc) and then store these coordinates into a data structure (e.g. a dictionary, but it could be another data structure).
For the sake of simplicity, I am just hardcoding the coordinates in the script.

Then, I get all possible pairs of segment without repetitions, so `["line_a", "line_b"]` is the same as `["line_b", "line_a"]`.

Then, check if the two segments intersect, using for instance the `shapely` library, or your custom function and, if they don't, add the pair to the `non_intersecting_segment_pairs` list.

```py
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import LineString

# Get segment coordinates from, for instance, json file and stored them into a data structure.

label_to_segment = {
    "segment_a": LineString([(0, 0), (0, 1)]),
    "segment_b": LineString([(0, -1), (1, 0)]),
    "segment_c": LineString([(-2, 3), (1, -8)]),
    "segment_d": LineString([(-1, 0), (-4, 3)]),
}

for label, segment in label_to_segment.items():
    plt.plot(*segment.xy, label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

segment_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(label_to_segment.keys(), 2))

non_intersecting_segment_pairs = []
for pairs in segment_pairs:
    segment_i = label_to_segment[pairs[0]]
    segment_j = label_to_segment[pairs[1]]
    if segment_i.intersection(segment_j).wkt == "LINESTRING EMPTY":
        non_intersecting_segment_pairs.append(pairs)
        
pprint(non_intersecting_segment_pairs)
```

```py
>>> pprint(non_intersecting_segment_pairs)
[('segment_a', 'segment_b'),
 ('segment_a', 'segment_c'),
 ('segment_a', 'segment_d'),
 ('segment_b', 'segment_c'),
 ('segment_b', 'segment_d')]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response! but the result you got is a intermediate product of my question. I would like to get how many classes of non-conflict segments exist. maybe I can explain more with your example: the answer I want to get is 2. the non-conflict combinations classes are [[a,b,c],[d]] or [[a,b,d],[c]]. c and d intersect with each other, so they will never belongs to one class, therefore the non-conflict classes number is 2.